# Weird Date object creation

Tags: javascript, node.js

This my `index.js` file:

```
console.log(
    "new Date(2022, 2, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0)",
    new Date(2022, 2, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0)
);
console.log(
    "new Date(2022, 4, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0)",
    new Date(2022, 4, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0)
);
```

And the output I'm getting is:

```
new Date(2022, 2, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0) 2022-03-23T00:00:00.000Z
new Date(2022, 4, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0) 2022-05-15T23:00:00.000Z
```

I'm expecting to see the `...05-16T00...` in the second, but somehow that is not that case.

I'm running node.js version 16.14.2, I tried to upgrade to 16.15.0. Also I tried 17.9.0 and 18.2.0

When I tried to put the code above to the browser or tried the https://codesandbox.io/, I've got what I'm expecting.

Comment: `new Date()` creates a datetime in the current locale. The time is correct it's just that daylight savings got in the way.

Comment: When calling `new Date()` with all the individual components, the date is processed in local time zone. You then see the date in UTC. It's one hour apart, which means that you are in a +1 time zone. The difference between March and May is because of daylight savings. There is no problem here, just the same point in time shown in two different ways.